# Prevent reload on Ajax.BeginForm

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor, ajax.beginform

How can I prevent page reloading when submitting form in partial view? There are a lot of examples but it seems that non of them is working for me. This is what I have. Partial view (Razor) which calls this:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveReply", "Home", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post" }, new { target = "_self" }))
{
    <div class="input-group wall-comment-reply" style="width:100%">
        @Html.Hidden("eventid", @item.EventID)
        <input name="txtReply" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type your message here...">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-chat" type="submit">
                <i class="fa fa-reply"></i> Reply
            </button>
        </span>
    </div>
}
```

Then I have my action method in the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public void SaveReply(string txtReply, string eventid)
{
    //some code

}
```

The controller action is fired but after that it is automatically redirected to localhost/home/SaveReply

Maybe the problem is that this partial view is rendered from string. I took the code from:

[How to render a Razor View to a string in ASP.NET MVC 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243433/how-to-render-a-razor-view-to-a-string-in-asp-net-mvc-3)

Also amongs other things i tried this:

http://geekswithblogs.net/blachniet/archive/2011/08/03/walkthrough-updating-partial-views-with-unobtrusive-ajax-in-mvc-3.aspx

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: try using the overload without the `routeValues` since you're not using them. i.e., remove the `null` parameter in your `Ajax.BeginForm`

Comment: This helped me greatly. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

I found the problem.

It seems that you need to reference the Unobtrusive scripts. Just install them from NuGet:

Install-Package Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax

And then reference it from the View that calls the Partial View:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
```

And miraculosly it works without any other changes. More explanations can be found here:

[[Why does Ajax.BeginForm replace my whole page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961157/why-does-ajax-beginform-replace-my-whole-page][1])

and here:

[[Why UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled = true disable my ajax to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208247/why-unobtrusivejavascriptenabled-true-disable-my-ajax-to-work][1])

It seems that you need to use it if you are using Ajax.* helpers in MVC 3 and higher.