# Model Validation issue in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-validation

Model:

```
 public class Employee
 {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [StringLength(10, MinimumLength = 5)]
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Range(1, 100)]
        public int Age { get; set; }
  }
```

I am new to asp.net MVC. I am providing the validations using Model data annotations.

My problem is that when `UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled` is `false` in `Web.Config` validations are no longer working even though `ClientValidationEnabled` is set to `true`?

Is Data Annotation only for Client Side because when I set `ClientValidationEnabled` to `false`, validatios are no longer working? I am really Confused.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208247/why-unobtrusivejavascriptenabled-true-disable-my-ajax-to-work first?  See if that helps you out with this question.

Comment: im still confused. lol

Comment: Ok. Does the explanation of those 2 parameters make sense? And - when you look at the html source for your page -- are all the js files mentioned in the post included?

Comment: Yes, all the js files included.